# Get all element/string following/preceding a certain string in a list Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of key words, and string/text example:

```
text='a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o'

k = ['e','i','k']
```

I am trying to get all the strings that appear before and after of a certain key words in k list.

```
                        
    v1_list=[]
    for v1 in text:
        if v1 in k:
        v1_list.append(text[text.index(v1):-1])
```

It gives `['d']` for `'e'` only.

My code only gives me before or next string `(v2:+1)` not all of the element in left. How to get all of the element in left/right side of a particular string.
I need, `['a','b','c','d']` for `'e'`(all the elements before `'e'` in a list) I am still learning, so kindly show me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you please add sample input and output

Comment: To get the all the before strings use `text[:text.index(v1)]` and to get all the after strings use `text[text.index(v1)+1:]`. Also a better example and formatting would help to understand more context.

Comment: @Sajjan. Thank you so much! it worked!. I got the first one #text[:text.index(v1)], start:0:stop untill index[v1]. but may I ask about the last one# text[text.index(v1)+1:] what does this +1 do here?

Comment: @SajjjanKumar The problem is index only return first occurrence for the element. if a certain element appears several times in a text. this index won't work for that. is there any other way to get all the occurrence of a element? other build in function rather than index?

Comment: @KuldeepSinghSidhu I am trying to edit but couldn't. still new to the system.

Comment: @KuldeepSinghSidhu I am trying to edit but couldn't. still new to the system. ' ' ' if text=['A','B', 'C', 'D', E', 'F','G', 'E'.'M','N'], k=['E']  [output]: {E, ['D'] ['F']} {E, ['G'] , ['M']} ' ' '. but now i can see index only gives me 1st occurrence of E. I hope I could explain it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
text='a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o'

k = ['e','i','k']

v1_list_right= list()
v1_list_left = list()
for v1 in text:
        if v1 in k:
         v1_list_right.append(text[text.index(v1)+1:])
         v1_list_left.append(text[:text.index(v1)])

print(v1_list_right)
print(v1_list_left)
```

It is basically , this gives you characters starting from 0 to your index number,

```
text[:text.index(v1)]
```

and this gives, starting from your next of your index number to the end of the array.

```
text[text.index(v1)+1:]
```

We use +1 here to pass your character, if we do not use +1.It adds also your character in to array but we are just looking for left or right.

However this code does not work for repeating characters. In case of having repeating characters, you can try this,

```
text='a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o i'

k = ['e','i','k']
idx = 0
v1_list_right= list()
v1_list_left = list()
index = 0
for character in k:
    while index < len(text):
        index = text.find(character, index)
        if index == -1:
            break
        v1_list_left.append(text[:index])
        index = index + 1
    index = 0


print(v1_list_left)
```

If you have a list instead of string, you can try this,

```
text = 'a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o i'
a = text.split()
k = ['e','i','k']
v1_list_right= list()
v1_list_left = list()
index = 0
for character in k:
    while index < len(a):
        if character == a[index]:
            print(a[:index])
        index = index + 1
    index = 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the details. But the problem is index only return first occurrence for the element. if a certain element appears several times. this index won't work. is there any other way to get all the occurrence of a element? other build in function rather than index.

Comment: I have edited my solution. You should check how find() function works in python. We are looking index by index for character and get index number by taking advantage of find() function.

Comment: it shows error in my function- list' object has no attribute 'find', I tried with enumerate too but gives me empty list or index out of range error for index+1. May I ask what idx=0 is used for?

Comment: Your text is a list or string ?

Comment: it's list ..text.split().

Comment: I have edited my code.  Find() function works for string not for list